# How to speed up my .bmp class?

Tags: c++, file, file-io, fstream, ofstream

Well greetings to you all :)

A few days ago I finally managed to create a functional C++ class to make .bmp images. Even though it's functional (no errors yet) it isn't efficient in terms of speed (in my opinion). Doing a few test to see how much time it took to write different sizes of images I ended up with these results:

```
Image Dimensions   Time taken(in seconds)     Comparison to the 1000x1000 image
10x100             0.0491                     x 1000 = 49.1 seconds
100x100            0.2471                     x 100  = 24.7 seconds
100x1000           2.3276                     x 10   = 23.3 seconds
1000x1000          22.515                     x 1    = 22.5 seconds
1000x10000         224.76                     \ 10   = 22.4 seconds
```

For example the 10x100 image had 1000 pixels (each with with a ARGB channel [32 bits or 4 bytes]) plus the 54 bytes for the header, it took 0.05 seconds to  write 4054 bytes (char).

I feel this is super slow, because my computer can copy a ~85MB file in like a second or two. I'm using fstream to do the writing to disk and any help to make the class go faster is appreciated. Thank You!!!

My class it's called SimpleBMP and here it is (I only put the revelent functions):

```
#include <fstream>


class SimpleBMP{
    struct PIXEL{
        unsigned char A, R, G, B;
    }*PixelArray;
    unsigned char *BMPHEADER, *BMPINFOHEADER;
    std::string DATA;
    unsigned int Size_Of_BMP, Size_Of_PixelArray;
    int BMP_Width, BMP_Height;

public:

void SetPixel(int Column, int Row, unsigned char A, unsigned char R, unsigned char G, unsigned char B){
    PixelArray[(Row*BMP_Width)+Column].A = A;
    PixelArray[(Row*BMP_Width)+Column].R = R;
    PixelArray[(Row*BMP_Width)+Column].G = G;
    PixelArray[(Row*BMP_Width)+Column].B = B;
};

bool MakeImage(std::string Name){
    Name.append(".bmp");
    std::ofstream OffFile(Name, std::ios::out|std::ios::binary);
    if(OffFile.is_open()){
        DATA.clear();
        for(int temp = 0; temp < 14; temp++){
            BMPHEADER[temp] = 0x00;
        };
        BMPHEADER[0] = 'B';
        BMPHEADER[1] = 'M';
        BMPHEADER[2] = Size_Of_BMP;
        BMPHEADER[3] = (Size_Of_BMP >> 8);
        BMPHEADER[4] = (Size_Of_BMP >> 16);
        BMPHEADER[5] = (Size_Of_BMP >> 24);
        BMPHEADER[10] = 0x36;



        for(int temp = 0; temp < 40; temp++){
            BMPINFOHEADER[temp] = 0x00;
        };
        BMPINFOHEADER[0] = 0x28;

        for(int temp = 0; temp < 4; temp++){
            BMPINFOHEADER[temp+4] = (BMP_Width >> (temp*8));
        };
        for(int temp = 0; temp < 4; temp++){
            BMPINFOHEADER[temp+8] = (BMP_Height >> (temp*8));
        };  
        BMPINFOHEADER[12] = 0x01;
        BMPINFOHEADER[14] = 0x20;

        for(int temp = 0; temp < 4; temp++){
            BMPINFOHEADER[temp+20] = (Size_Of_PixelArray >> (temp*8));
        };
        BMPINFOHEADER[24] = 0x13;
        BMPINFOHEADER[25] = 0x0b;
        BMPINFOHEADER[28] = 0x13;
        BMPINFOHEADER[29] = 0x0b;



        for(int temp = 0; temp < 14; temp++){
            DATA.push_back(BMPHEADER[temp]);
        };
        for(int temp = 0; temp < 40; temp++){
            DATA.push_back(BMPINFOHEADER[temp]);
        };
        for(int temp = 0; temp < (Size_Of_PixelArray/4); temp++){
            DATA.push_back(PixelArray[temp].B);
            DATA.push_back(PixelArray[temp].G);
            DATA.push_back(PixelArray[temp].R);
            DATA.push_back(PixelArray[temp].A);
        };  
        OffFile.write(DATA.c_str(), Size_Of_BMP);
        OffFile.close();
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
};
```

};

Comment: One thing would be to call `DATA.reserve()` to preallocate the correct amount of space for the data. This will eliminate a lot of unnecessary copying. Also make sure you are compiling in release mode instead of debug.

Comment: Are you sure the timing is in second and you only profile the write function. I don't think that it will take 22 seconds to copy a 1000x1000 RGBA8 image on disk. Your code is not that bad and optimizing the unnecessary buffer copies won't solve the 22 seconds problem.

Comment: This won't be necessary in all case, but you should prefer '++temp' instead of 'temp++'.

Comment: @a.lasram Well the DATA.reserve() made it around 2.2% faster. And I also think that that's too much time, but it's all the program does. The .SetPixel() loop I made took like 0.3 seconds. The rest was the .MakeImage() and finally the program ended. I'll try and keep making improvements.

Comment: make sure your instrumentation system gives details specific to "toOffFile.write"

Comment: @CaptainObvlious Man make your comment an answer. When I changed it to release it became like... I have no words. A 10,000x10,000 Image took 8.8 seconds. Though why is is faster in release mode???

Comment: Because release mode disables several debug features, and enables optimization that allows the compiler to make MUCH better code. 3-5x improvement isn't unheard of.

Comment: @MatsPetersson No kidding. If I use the table in my question a 10,000x10,000 image would have taken more than 2,000 seconds, the same as more than half a hour. But in release it took me the previously mentioned 8.8 seconds. That's a speed increase of 22,627% (around 227 times faster). Now I'll probably always use release mode, I'll use debug when I'm not sure the code I wrote will work.

Comment: Yes, that's what the two different build modes are for - and 200x improvement is probably caused by a combination of a lot of things, including, a major one being "not using debug mode `operator[]` for your vector and string classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When running tests you should compile your project in *release* mode. *Debug* mode in most environments introduces additional checks and code. The *debug* libraries linked can also include additional checks such as bounds checking and validation of iterators that are not present in *release* mode. All of this can introduce performance hits that are not present in release mode.

There are other optimizations that you can apply such as reserving memory in `DATA` before loading the data. This will reduce the number of copies that need to be made when the buffer is expanded. Although the performance gain may not be significant it can definitely help. I suggest running your code through a profiler to see where all of the bottlenecks are and optimize accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If you know you are on a little-endian machine, you can completely skip the re-packing of the data, and just store the pixelarray data directly.

```
OffFile.Write((char *)&PixelArray, Size_Of_BMP);
```

It may not be quite as portable, but it will certainly speed up the saving to file.

(And you could have a

```
#ifdef LITTLE_ENDIAN
struct PIXEL{
    unsigned char A, R, G, B;
};
#else
struct PIXEL{
    unsigned char B, G, R, A;
};
#endif    

PIXEL *PixelArray;
```

in the declaration.

Comment: True, but I'm intending to combine this with a noise function and it'll have to make it portable for the end-users with a big endian machine. Though it's a good thing to know this is possible.